# Why does this not invert the binary tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm not sure why this code to invert a binary tree does not work. It works when I invert the values instead of the actual nodes but in that case does not work if a node is null which is why I need to use the nodes for inversion.

You can uncomment the print lines to see it's hitting the correct values and changing the tree as it should be changed but it returns the original array.

```
    class Solution {
        public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {
            if(root == null) {
                return null;
            }
            invertBinaryTree(root.left, root.right);
            return root;
        }
        
    private static void invertBinaryTree(TreeNode l, TreeNode r) {
    if(l == null || r == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    TreeNode temp = l;
    l = r;
    r = temp;
        
//     System.out.println(l.val);
//     System.out.println(r.val);
        
    
    invertBinaryTree(l.left, r.right);
    invertBinaryTree(l.right, r.left);
        

}
}
```

Comment: Inverting the values will work.
Also, you are returning if even one of them is null. The condition should be 
if (l == null && r == null)

Comment: Because you're changing local variables only. To invert the tree you have to do something like `TreeNode temp = node.left; node.left = node.right; node.right = temp;`

Comment: @PavelSmirnov but I'm passing in the right & left from the root of the original tree. Doesn't it carry over by reference?

Comment: @sathvikp inverting the values won't work, one side could be null in which case it's still a binary tree but you can't look for it's value then

Answer (score 1):

Java uses "pass by value" and not "pass by reference" for method parameters. This means that if you pass an object to a method, you can update the object's member variables inside the method and the changes will be reflected in the calling method, however if you overwrite the parameter to refer to a different object (like you are doing by changing the values of l and r) the reference to that object won't be updated in the calling method. You can rewrite your function to something like this:

```
private static void invertBinaryTree(TreeNode t) {
     TreeNode temp = t.left;
     t.left = t.right;
     t.right = temp;

     if(t.left != null)
         invertBinaryTree(t.left);
     if(t.right != null)
         invertBinaryTree(t.right);
}
```

Then you would just call it on the top of the tree by passing `invertBinaryTree(root);`